# Calculation of an equation via Jacobi Triple Product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Using the identity $$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-x^{2n}\right)\left(1+yx^{2n-1}\right)\left(1+y^{-1}x^{2n-1}\right)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}y^nx^{n^2},$$ show that $$ \left[\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a^n)\right]^3=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)a^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}.$$

Comment: is the identity correct? what if $x=y=1$?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento it's valid for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ and $y \neq 0$. And Li Li, what substitutions have you tried?

Comment: I would start with $x=\sqrt{a}$ and $y=-\sqrt{a}$

Comment: @kobe The same  with the try of Arnaldo Nascimento. But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first identity in question is more popularly known as [*Jacobi Triple Product identity*](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html) and the identity to be proved is also known by the name of *Jacobi's identity*. Getting the second identity from the first is not direct, but at the same time not too difficult.

---

Let's put $y = -xt$ where $t$ is real and $t \neq 1$ to get $$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})(1 - x^{2n}t)(1 - x^{2n - 2}t^{-1}) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}t^{n}x^{n(n + 1)}$$ or $$(t - 1)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})(1 - x^{2n}t)(1 - x^{2n}t^{-1}) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}t^{n + 1}x^{n(n + 1)}$$ Now we can pair the terms corresponding to indices $n$ and $-(n + 1)$ in the sum on right to get $$(t - 1)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})(1 - x^{2n}t)(1 - x^{2n}t^{-1}) = \sum_{n = 0 }^{\infty}(-1)^{n}x^{n(n + 1)}\{t^{n + 1} - t^{-n}\}$$ or $$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})(1 - x^{2n}t)(1 - x^{2n}t^{-1}) = \sum_{n = 0 }^{\infty}(-1)^{n}x^{n(n + 1)}\cdot\frac{t^{n + 1} - t^{-n}}{t - 1}$$ Letting $t \to 1$ we get $$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})^{3} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(2n + 1)x^{n(n + 1)}$$ Replacing $x$ by $\sqrt{a}$ we get the desired identity in question.